# Dijit Combobox filter autocomplete

Tags: combobox, dojo

I'm using dijit combobox for populating a JSON List. Also I'm using ItemFileReadStore for getting the JSON data from the server. Once the data is downloaded, when I click on the combobox it shows all the data. But I don't want the user to see all the data. The user should see the list only when he types something. I tried using queryExpr parameter-${0}*. But at that time the list is not populated.Can someone please help me to fix it?
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Apps

Comment: Do you observe this behavior with several browsers (IE6, IE7, FF ...) ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Philippe. I see this behavior on all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet, largely inspired from the [Dojo ComboBox example](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-2-dijit/form-validation-specialized-input/auto-completer) works does not "show all the data" with Dojo verion 1.3.0 (17136).

```
 <input dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox"
        store="stateStore"
        searchAttr="name"
        name="state2"
        onChange="setVal2" />
```

I played a bit with the comboBox properties (autoComplete, hasDownArrow ...) and couldn't reproduce the described behavior. Could you post a minimal example?

Comment: <input type="text"name="countrySelected" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" store="countryStore" autocomplete="false" hasDownArrow="false" searchattr="countryName"  id="countryId" onChange="testingFunction();"invalidmessage="Enter a valid Country"/>
    </form>

    <div dojotype="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" 
         jsId="countryStore"
          url="<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(countryUrl.toString())%>
    </div>

Initially it doesn't load all the entries. When we start typing autocomplete works.After that if we clear the text field, all the entries are shown. Can you please help me?

Comment: This seems to be the behavior of the widget, I'm afraid you will have to customize the widget - or ask the Dojo people.